# Is there any model driven editor for entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad, utilities, model-driven-development

The idea with model-driven development is to automize otherwise repetitive tasks.

LinqPad makes it possible to load an assembly and an optional connection string and start querying a database.

In the same way it should be possible to write an editor where you can CRUD objects. A few of the ORM tools I have been using offer such editors.

Does that editor exist for EF?

Comment: It may help to provide examples of editors from other ORMs so it is more clear what kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Well, those two tools I have been working with the most are not that well-known. One was Bold for Delphi which had run-time model-driven GUI and a tool ("model runner" or something) where you could open a model and a database and explore the contents. The other is called WMBOF which is developed by WM-data. It contained an editor where you could populate a database with objects, change their properties, link them to eachother, delete them. In short, do the CRUD operations I request. Such an editor is nothing to ship to customers but a handy tool for the programmer to change some objects.

Comment: Here's a good article on the benefits of model-driven application development and it also shows a glimpse of what a run-time model-driven editor could look like. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621668.aspx)